# Background color visible outside of css mask-image on inline elements in Safari

Tags: css

I have an strange issue on Safari Browsers.
In Safari browser the background color is visible outside the mask-image.
Strangely, this error occurs only in inline elements.
Is there any way to mask the outer area as well?

Screenshot in Chrome:

[image]

Screenshot in Safari:

[image]

```css
p {
  font-family: "Arial";
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.iconlink {
  color: #ff00000;
}

.iconlink::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline;
    mask-image: url('https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/masking/star.svg');
    -webkit-mask-image: url('https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/masking/star.svg');
    mask-size: 1em;
    -webkit-mask-size: 1em;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center left;
    -webkit-mask-mask-position: center left;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<p>
this is an <a href="#" class="iconlink">iconlink</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show a screen of the issue and of what is excepted? Here is what I have with chrome: https://prnt.sc/O0AZNs9hM3bh

Comment: I forgot to add the vendor prefixes for Chrome. Now, the star is rendered in Chrome.

Comment: Appears to have to do with the fact that you are using `padding-right: 1.5em;` to give that pseudo element a "width". Making that `padding-right: 1em; margin-right: .5em;` instead, gets me the same visual result as in Chrome.

Comment: That will remove the red area to the right, but the is still a red line above the mask.

Comment: Not for me, and it wasn't there to begin with. This is what your snippet above looks like for me in Safari (16.4), after making the change I suggested: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C1fA.png Maybe you need to reduce the line-height for the pseudo element a bit, or explicitly specify the height as 1em as well.

Comment: I have increased the font-size of the p-tag. Now you can see a red line at the top and bottom. The line-height has no influence on the lines. Tested on Mac OS Safari 16.5